# Interpretting $X|\mathcal{F}$ as a random variable?

Tags: probability-theory

Suppose $X$ is random variable and $\mathcal{F} \subset \sigma(X)$ is some sigma-algebra. Then the term $\mathbb{P}(X=x|\mathcal{F})$ makes sense.

Hence I think it also makes sense to consider $X|\mathcal{F}$ as random variable. We know that conditional probability $\mathbb{E}(f(X)|\mathcal{F})$ is randomvariable over $\mathcal{F}$, and $\mathbb{P}(X=x|\mathcal{F}) = \mathbb{E}(1_{X=x}|\mathcal{F})$ is a random variable over $\mathcal{F}$.

So does it make sense to identify rv $X|\mathcal{F}$ with rv $\mathbb{E}(1_{X=x}|\mathcal{F})$ which is rv over $\sigma(X) \times \mathcal{F}$.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to the site! Please keep only one question per post if you're asking about a specific topic. At the moment, it is unclear to me what you mean by "what does it look like". Please explain what you mean by that for the maximum chance that you get a suitable answer!

Comment: What does it mean to say 'r.v. over $\sigma (X)\times \mathcal F$'? You need  a probabiltiy space to define a r.v. $X|\mathcal F$ cannot be considered as  a r.v. in any reasonable way.

Comment: @geetha290krm because for fix $x$, $\mathbb{E}(X=x|\mathcal{F})$ is a rv over $\mathcal{F}$, I thought by varying $x$, the expression $\mathbb{E}(X|\mathcal{F})$ will be rv over $\sigma(X) \times \mathcal{F}$. Also assume underlying probability space $(\Sigma,\sigma(X),\mathbb{P})$.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai rv means random variable

Comment: It confuses me why you added the "so" back in the last sentence again, was there any particular reason for it? owo

Comment: Why not use the conditional expectation $E[X| {\cal F}]$? This is an ${\cal F}$ measurable rv.